# What is the Generating Function for the sequence of reciprocal triangular numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, generating-functions

Starting from
$$0+1x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{4}x^4+\dots : GF=-\ln(1-x)$$
I can get to
$$1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{3}x^2+\frac{1}{4}x^3+\frac{1}{5}x^4\dots : GF=-\frac{ln(1-x)}{x}$$
and I'd now like to subtract
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{1}{5}x^3+\frac{1}{6}x^4\dots : GF=?$$
with a view to then doubling everything to get the generating function for
$$1+\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{6}x^2+\frac{1}{10}x^3+\frac{1}{15}x^4+\frac{1}{21}x^5\dots : GF=?$$
I feel this should be easy but can't seem to get it exactly

(If I right shift the $1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{3}x^2+\dots$ I'll be subtracting  an unwanted $2$.)

Comment: Just pass the 2 to the other side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you made a mistake in the second series:
$$1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{3}x^2+\frac{1}{4}x^3+\frac{1}{5}x^4\dots : GF=-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}.$$
Then
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{1}{5}x^3+\frac{1}{6}x^4\dots : GF=\frac{\frac{-\ln(1-x)}{x}-1}{x} = -\frac{x+\ln(1-x)}{x^2}.$$
(That is, subtract $1$ from the first series and divide by $x$.)
Subtracting the two and multiply by two, giving
$$1+\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{6}x^2+\frac{1}{10}x^3+\frac{1}{15}x^4+\frac{1}{21}x^5\dots : GF=\frac{2(x+\ln(1-x)-x\ln(1-x))}{x^2}.$$

Comment: Many thanks for a clear explanation. I’ve corrected the typo in the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you substract first and second, you get
$$-1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{6}x^2+\frac{1}{12}x^3+\frac{1}{20}x^4\dots=f(x)-g(x)$$
Then multiplying by 2, you get
$$-2+x+\frac{1}{3}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{1}{10}x^4+\dots=2(f(x)-g(x))$$
So, 
$$x+\frac{1}{3}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{1}{10}x^4+\dots=2(f(x)-g(x))+2$$
Finally, dividing by $x$.
$$1+\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{6}x^2+\frac{1}{10}x^3+\dots=\frac{2(f(x)-g(x))+2}{x}$$

Comment: Thanks so much guys, that makes perfect sense !